# How to connect garbage disposal when drain is too short

Tags: garbage-disposal

I removed the old garbage disposal and only have to hook up the drain on the new one, but it is acting like it is too short. Here is the before photo:

[image: Old Disposal connection]

And here is the new one (if you look closely, there is a gap between the drain and the trap and I'm just not sure what to do. All the instructions I've found so far just say, 'connect it' and that's just not enough details for my first plumbing job. :) I'd really appreciate some newbie hand-holding on this one!

[image]

Comment: Could you remove & reuse that metal pipe from the old disposal unit? it looks a little longer than the black plastic one on the new unit.

Comment: I could try that, but when I hold them next to one another they look exactly the same length. Also, I'm not sure how the gasket and threads work together to connect a piece with no threads with one that does have threads.

Comment: I take it all back. Just to make sure I wasn't deluding myself, I detached the new plastic piece and put it next to the old metal one and the metal one *is* longer! I put it back on with the new gasket and it is all working now. Thank you for questioning my assumptions!

Comment: Those appear to be slip joints with compression gaskets, not "threaded".

Answer (score 1):

Original drain was longer. That piece has been added back on and is in use now. Props to [brhans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/33897/brhans) for the tip!

Comment: You probably could've added a tailpiece extension, but glad you got it sorted.

Comment: That does look like it would have worked. I just needed the right terminology. Thanks!

Comment: It says I can only accept the answer in 2 days. I'll be sure to do that then.